# When the torsion tensor vaishes but the lie bracket is nonzero

Tags: differential-geometry, connections

My question is to the same effect as the question [Difference between torsion and Lie bracket](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2499466/difference-between-torsion-and-lie-bracket)

Let's suppose we have a situation where the lie bracket is nonzero but the torsion tensor vanishes.

Let $[X,Y]=A≠0$

Since the torsion tensor vanishes and $T(X,Y):=\nabla_XY-\nabla_YX-[X,Y]$ we have $A=\nabla_XY-\nabla_YX$

In a situation like this, does $\nabla_XY-\nabla_YX$ "compensate" for the non-closing of the  flow lines?

Whenever I've identified a connection to be torsion free I always end up with $0=\nabla_XY-\nabla_YX$. I know this can't be the only type of situation where a connection is torsion-free, and thus I want to better understand the situations where $0≠\nabla_XY-\nabla_YX$

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150034/discussion-on-question-by-simon-m-when-the-torsion-tensor-vaishes-but-the-lie-br); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.